# Trying to understand installing a CGI script

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi, chmod

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

```
#!/usr/bin/python

 print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
 print '<html>'
 print '<head>'
 print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
 print '</head>'
 print '<body>'
 print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
 print '</body>'
 print '</html>'
```

What is the significance of `#!/usr/bin/python`

It says to save file as `hello.py` and save it to `/var/www/cgi-bin` directory but I don't have this directory, should I create one?

> Before running your CGI program, make sure you have change mode of file using chmod 755 hello.py UNIX command to make file executable.

but where to (how to) execute this `chmod` command? should I include `$chmod 755 "/location of hello(.py).../"` in `hello.py`?

Comment: Please use a better question title; most questions ask to explain something.

Comment: Learning how to write CGI scripts in 2014 is kind of silly. Use a WSGI framework.

Comment: sorry for asking like a noob..I am learning coding as hobby .. will improve myself..thanks for suggesting wsgi framework ..will look into it.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the `#!/usr/bin/python` line on *nix systems to tell the shell how to interpret this script and where your interpreter is in the system. This is called the shebang line.

The `chmod 755 hello.py` command is a unix shell  command to change the permissionson of the file and make it executable. Doing this you can run the script without having to do `python hello.py` but instead `./hello.py` .

From my understanding you are a windows user. In this case, you don't have to do all of this. Just save the file as `hello.py` and that's it.

This post on tutorialspoint.com implies that you already have an HTTP server running that supports cgi and has a default web directory of `/var/www/`

Comment: Thanks.. yes I agree.. as I dont have http server running.. I will mostly ignore this part of tutorial from tutorialspoint.com ..thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

The line `#!/usr/bin/python` is a signal to the shell (the program that handles your keyboard input and runs commands for you) that this file is a script that can be handled by the program  shown. It's called a 'shebang' or sometime 'hashbang'.

In this case the shebang tells your shel to run the program it finds at `/usr/bin/python` and submit this script to it. There's more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

`chmod` is a general command for setting permissions on files. You execute it from the command line like any other command. The numerical values for the permissions can be a bit cryptic, but they're made up of binary bits that indicate certain permissions. Changing a permission to 755 specifically indicates that the owner of the file can execute this as a program, rather than just treating it as a block of text. Personally I prefer the mor descriptive `chmod u+x filename` - add execute for the user.

You can find a fuller description of `chmod` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Comment: u+x is completely useless for a CGI script; the owner of the file will almost certainly not be the user the web server runs as. It's not "more descriptive" since it means something completely different from 755.